# Can a for-each loop differentiate between regular and const iterator in a templated class?

Tags: c++, templates

I made a templated class with 2 different iterators, a regular one and a constIterator.
When using a for-each loop, does the complier know which iterator to use according to the specific instance of the object, whether it is const or not?
Sorry if this is a dumb question, I just started learning C++.

Comment: Instead of trying to describe your code, *show it*. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre], that you copy-paste as text.

Comment: Take a look at overloading `const` for member functions

Comment: As for your question, it's really irrelevant if you're using templates or not. And it's up to the compiler to decide if it can use constant iterators or not. For example if you iterate using values or constant references, it can easily see that the container will not be modified and can use constant iterators.

Comment: If the object is `const` it'll use the `begin()` and `end()` member functions that are `const` qualified.

Comment: The magic is usually in the object (typically a container) itself. See e.g. [`std::vector::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin), notice two overloads: overload (1) returns a non-const `iterator` and can only be called on a non-const `vector`, while overload (2) is selected when called on a const `vector`, and returns `const_iterator`

Comment: `for (auto&& x : v) { /*...*/ }` the `x` is `const` if `v` is `const`.

Answer (score 1):

A range-based `for` loop calls `begin` and `end` on the range expression (which would be of your class type in this case and potentially `const`-qualified) to obtain iterators.

Whether these functions return const iterators or not depends on how you implemented them for your class. If you implemented them correctly, they should have a non-`const` overload and a `const` overload each, with each returning the appropriate iterator type.